# Non-US citizen applying for a Spain tourist visa with expiring visa

Tags: schengen, europe, spain, f1-visas

I am an Indian citizen studying in the US on an f-1 visa. My program end date is 14th of December 2018, and I am going back to India on the 19th of December.
My travel plans -
India to Spain 24th of December
Spain to India 4th of January
This means I don't have enough time to apply for a Spain visa from the consulate in India. So I have to apply from the Spanish consulate in DC. However, while talking to the DC consulate, the person on the phone said since my i20/f-1 expires on the 14th of December, I can't apply for a visa from within the US. But I don't understand why this is a problem since I am returning to India - my home country, not the US, from Spain. From what I read online, someone successfully got a visa in a similar situation (they showed a ticket back to their home country). Is there anything I can do here?

Comment: They told you the policy. That is their policy. If you read this forum you will see similar questions to yours. Your option is to go directly to India, Schengen countries will not issue you a visa under your circumstances.

Comment: It sounds like they are not following the rules. You are legally resident in the US therefore that is where you should apply from. You don't have enough time to make an application from within India. So this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I spoke to them again, and showed them that I have applied for an extension for my visa. That was enough for them! So relieved I that i'm getting my winter holiday!

Answer (score 1):

According to OP:

> I spoke to them again, and showed them that I have applied for an extension for my visa. That was enough for them! So relieved I that i'm getting my winter holiday!